# simple jquery image change onclick failing

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery image switch that is failing.

```
$('.heart_img').click(function()
    {
        var heart_type = $(this).attr('src');

        //alert( heart_type );

        if ( heart_type == 'images/unheart.png')
        {
            //alert('uheart');
            $(this).attr('src','images/heart.png');
        }
        else if ( heart_type == 'images/heart.png');
        {
            $(this).attr('src','images/unheart.png');
        }

    });
```

The alerts fire correctly when not commented out so and the images are in the correct place so I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Is the heart_img a class or an ID? If there's only one, it's usually better to have an ID, since there can be more than one of a class.... What's the HTML look like?

Comment: You can remove if(...) after the else if there are only 2 images.

Comment: @Peter:Um.. .heart_img means it is a class? #heart_img would be an id?

Comment: `.something` is a class selector and `#something` is an id selector. You are having only one image then give an id and use an id selector.

Comment: @ian - what is your jQuery version? and html please...

Comment: @ian, I know... just surprised

Comment: @Rahul. I have a lot of images, thus the class. @Reigel I am using the latest jQuery.

PHP/HTML: echo '<div class="heart"><img class="heart_img" id="heart_img_'.$row['id'].'" src="images/unheart.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Heart!"></div>';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem:

Semicolon in your if else

```
else if ( heart_type == 'images/heart.png');
```

should be

```
else if ( heart_type == 'images/heart.png')
```

even better

```
else
```

Answer (score 0):

@ian, the image may be in the correct place but the src can't see it.  try something like `"//images/unheart.png"`

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer but for improvements... if you're in jQuery 1.4, you can

```
$('.heart_img').click(function(){
     $(this).attr('src', function(index,heart_type){
        if ( heart_type.indexOf('unheart.png') != -1 )
        {
            return 'images/heart.png';
        }
        else if ( heart_type.indexOf('heart.png') != -1 )
        {
            return 'images/unheart.png';
        }
        return heart_type;
     });
});
```

or much better,

```
$('.heart_img').click(function(){
     $(this).attr('src', function(index,heart_type){
            return ( heart_type.indexOf('unheart.png') != -1 )? 'images/heart.png':'images/unheart.png';           
     });
});
```